# I am struggling to align three images in my header

Tags: css

I am trying to align three images in a header div. I need one image on the left - once centered - and an image on the right. I have the image on the left and the centered image in place. However, I cannot get the image I need on the right to display on the right of the centered image. If I float:left the centered image it messes up my centered image in various browsers. The image I want on the right displays on the left of the centered image. How do I get it on the right side of the centered image? Thank you very much.

Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<div class="header">

<div class="headerLeft">

<img src="salogo_lg.jpg"
 width="105"
 height="115"
 alt="Salvation Army Logo" />

</div> <!-- closing tag of headerLeft-->

<div class="headerCenter">

<img src="logo85.jpg"
width="485"
height="93"
alt="Salvation Army" />

</div>  <!-- closing tag of headerCenter -->

<div class="headerRight">

<img src="salogo_lg.jpg"
width="105"
height="115"
alt="Salvation Army Logo" />

</div>  <!-- closing tag of headerRight -->


</div> <!-- closing tag of header -->
```

CSS:

```
.header{
width: 100%;
height: 115px;
background-color: #0B0B3B;
margin-bottom: -15px;
}

.headerLeft{
float: left;
width: 105px;
height: 115px;
}

.headerCenter{
display: inline-block;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
width: 485px;
height: 93px;
}

.headerRight{
float: left;
text-align: right;
margin-left: 15px;
width: 105px;
height: 115px;
}
```

Comment: shouldn't your headerRight be float:right?

Comment: fiddle with headerRight float:right http://jsfiddle.net/6eqksnrf/

Comment: I have not worked with jsfiddle before. I'm assuming the code is displayed in the area to the lower right? Thank you!!

Comment: yes! the code result is displayed there

Comment: Hard to test without any real images, though ...

Comment: Sorry I'm using Bitnami and using my computer as the server. The images are not uploaded onto the web. I'm studying HTML5 and CSS3 so this is not a live site. Thank you.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand the answer below.

Comment: Float:right doesn't solve the problem, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

**Quick answer :**

```css
*
{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

header
{
    background: grey;
    color: white;
    padding: 1em;
    position: relative;
    height: 5em;
    width: 100;
}

img
{
    display: block;
    height: 3em;
    margin: auto;
}

img.right
{
    position: absolute;
    right: 1em;
    top: 1em;
}

img.left
{
    left: 1em;
    position: absolute;
    top: 1em;
}
```

```html
<header>
    <img src="http://25.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_m9gus8QYjY1rw0ggfo3_r5_400.gif" alt="" class="left" />
    <img src="http://t1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRBzTbPH8FRYR0HRqTmXnwSO4GgLbFO6rpALpwynKRr4SM_nTCywQQO6qvDcg" alt="" class="center" />
    <img src="https://c2.staticflickr.com/4/3016/3071708735_ddaf5d361b.jpg" alt="" class="right" />
</header>
```

Comment: I'm sorry I don't quite understand this answer.

Comment: Tell me what is unclear to you and I will try to explain as much as possible /!\ there may be other/easier methods, but this one works

Comment: I'm not familiar with box sizing. Where does it go in the HTML? Doesn't using position:absolute create other problems?

Comment: see this about box-sizing :
https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing / http://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/ --- `position: absolute` has to be used carefully, but it's quite compatible across browsers and it provided a quick solution to your problem.

Comment: If any of these answers has proven to be useful, please accept it :)

Answer (score 0):

To avoid using `position: absolute;`, I'd recommend using `calc` to help out, and wrapping the `.headerCenter` in `.headerCenterWrapper` as I have below.

CSS:

```
.headerLeft {
  width: 105px;
  height: 115px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.headerCenterWrapper {
  width: calc(100% - 220px); /* Using a number slightly more than the sum of the side images' widths (210 px) to be safe */
  height: 115px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}

.headerCenter {
  width: 50px;
  height: 115px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.headerRight {
  width: 105px;
  height: 115px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

And the HTML:

```
<header class="header">
  <img src="" alt="" class="headerLeft"/>
  <div class="headerCenterWrapper">
    <img src="" alt="" class="headerCenter" />
  </div>
  <img src="" alt="" class="headerRight" />
</header>
```

Comment: I appreciate this but it doesn't work. The center image isn't centered.

Comment: Sorry, typo. Should've been `display: inline-block;` for `.headerCenter`. Give it a shot now.

Comment: Andrew, thank you but it still doesn't work. The center image is off to the left and the right image is still on the left side.

Comment: Hang on a minute Andrew. I'm still working on what you provided.

Comment: Andrew......PERFECTO!!!! Thank you SO MUCH....I've been working on this for hours..........

Comment: Just one more...should there not be a .header class in the css?

Comment: Well...spoke too soon. In Safri and IE the center image is not centered and the right image is not all the way to the right.

Comment: Should work on Safari and IE as well...not sure why it's giving you problems. There might be an issue elsewhere in your code that's causing it to render differently across browsers.

Comment: Well, I'm kind of worn out. I need to chill been on this for hours...I really appreciate you man.

Answer (score 0):

> css

```
.headerLeft{
float: left;
width: 33.33%;
height: 115px;
}

.headerCenter{
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
width: 33.33%;
height: 115px;
float:left;
text-align:center;
}

.headerRight{
float: right;
width: 33.33%;
height: 115px;
text-align:right;
}
```

> html

```
<div class="header">

<div class="headerLeft">

<img src="manish.png"
 width="105"
 height="115"
 alt="Salvation Army Logo" />

</div> <!-- closing tag of headerLeft-->

<div class="headerCenter">

<img src="manish.png"
width="105"
height="115"
alt="Salvation Army" />

</div>  <!-- closing tag of headerCenter -->

<div class="headerRight">

<img src="manish.png"
width="105"
height="115"
alt="Salvation Army Logo" />

</div>  <!-- closing tag of headerRight -->


</div>
```